# Writing k6 outputs to Victoria Metrics

Tags: influxdb, k6, victoriametrics

I'm using Victoria Metrics as a metric storage. I would like to use VM rather than using InfluxDB

In this case I just port forwarded to my VM port then run;

```
k6 run --out influxdb=http://127.0.0.1:8480/k6 click_performancetest.js --http-debug="full"
```

However when I do it, getting this;

> requestURI: /write?consistency=&db=k6&precision=ns&rp=; cannot parse
> path "/write": cannot find {prefix}\n" output=InfluxDBv1

Is there any blog, article or suggestion for using Victoria metrics using k6 with rather than using InfluxDB?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is Victoria Metrics compatible with InfluxDB or why do you expect `influxdb=http://your-victoria-metrics-server/k6` to work? I don't see Victoria Metrics in <https://k6.io/docs/getting-started/results-output/#external-outputs>. There's an open GitHub issue about adding more external outputs: <https://github.com/grafana/k6/issues/343>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is likely you run [cluster version of VictoriaMetrics](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/Cluster-VictoriaMetrics.html) instead of [single-node VictoriaMetrics](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/). The cluster version of VictoriaMetrics has different urls for data ingestion because of [multitenancy support](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/Cluster-VictoriaMetrics.html) - see [these docs](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/Cluster-VictoriaMetrics.html#url-format) for details. That's why you need to send data from k6 to the url like `http://vminsert:8480/insert/0/influx/write` .

Comment: Thanks for answering @valyala. This is actually a solution, but seems there are some stability issues when using this.

Comment: @BerkayKirmizioglu , could you provide more details regarding stability issues?

Answer (score 0):

@valyala , I am still seeing the below error even after using the right URL .

requestURI: /write?consistency=&db=insert%2F0%2Finflux%2Fapi%2Fv2%2Fwrite&precision=ns&rp=; cannot parse path "/write": cannot find {prefix} in "/write"; expecting /{prefix}/{tenantID}/{suffix} format; see [https://docs.victoriametrics.com/Cluster-VictoriaMetrics.html#url-format\n"](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/Cluster-VictoriaMetrics.html#url-format%5Cn%22) output=InfluxDBv1

And below is the URL that I configured

--out influxdb=http://vminsert-victoria-metrics.victoriametrics.svc.cluster.local:8480/insert/0/influx/api/v2/write

I donot see any issue with my vmui with select, not seeing any issue with vminsert pod as well.

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/274937/valyala

Comment: From the provided error message, the path used by k6 is the following `/write?consistency=&db=insert/0/influx/api/v2/write&precision=ns&rp=`. Is there a way in k6 to specify custom path for influxdb output? Have you tried setting `K6_INFLUXDB_ADDR=http://vminsert-victoria-metrics.victoriametrics.svc.cluster.local:8480/insert/0/influx/api/v2`?